# ChatGPT doesnt want to answer correctly based on prepared prompt

Tags: rest, prompt, openai-api

Now I am researching chat GPT prompt before requesting paid chatGPT API.
but my prompt cannot make ChatGPT understand the requirements.
I need help fixing it how to make a proper prompt, providing recommended link/docs to learn is also appreciated.

problem:

1. returning food that contain allergy
2. the currency not following the country/location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I removed some stuff that seemed unnecessary and tried the new [JSON mode](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/json-mode) and got the right response.  With that being said, though, LLM's are not deterministic and errors can happen. You could try to [fine tune your model](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/fine-tuning) to decrease the chances of errors cropping up or somehow check for keywords after the response has been given or make multiple calls to the api asking to double-check for allergens and correctness.

```py
import os
from openai import OpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
  response_format={ "type": "json_object" },
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": '''You are a recipe generator designed to take allergies, goals, country, budget and interests and output 8 recipes as JSON format with status and data which should contain ingredients, total_calories, nutrition, budget.*allergies must be  avoided! NEVER RETURN any food that contains allergens!'''},
    {"role": "user", "content": '''allergies: poultry, nuts. goals: boost athletic performance because i am fat and can only do 20 push ups. country: UK budget: 5-20 USD Dollars '''

}
  ]
)
print(response.choices[0].message.content)
```

```json
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "recipe_name": "Quinoa Salad with Roasted Vegetables",
      "ingredients": [
        "quinoa",
        "bell peppers",
        "zucchini",
        "red onion",
        "olive oil",
        "lemon juice",
        "garlic",
        "fresh parsley",
        "salt",
        "pepper"
      ],
      "total_calories": 320,
      "nutrition": {
        "carbs": "40g",
        "protein": "8g",
        "fat": "14g"
      },
      "budget": "10 USD"
    },
    {
      "recipe_name": "Black Bean and Sweet Potato Tacos",
      "ingredients": [
        "black beans",
        "sweet potatoes",
        "taco shells",
        "avocado",
        "tomato",
        "red cabbage",
        "lime",
        "cilantro",
        "cumin",
        "paprika",
        "salt",
        "pepper"
      ],
      "total_calories": 380,
      "nutrition": {
        "carbs": "45g",
        "protein": "10g",
        "fat": "15g"
      },
      "budget": "15 USD"
    },
    {
      "recipe_name": "Mediterranean Chickpea Salad",
      "ingredients": [
        "chickpeas",
        "cucumber",
        "tomato",
        "red onion",
        "kalamata olives",
        "feta cheese",
        "olive oil",
        "red wine vinegar",
        "oregano",
        "salt",
        "pepper"
      ],
      "total_calories": 290,
      "nutrition": {
        "carbs": "35g",
        "protein": "12g",
        "fat": "13g"
      },
      "budget": "10 USD"
    },
    {
      "recipe_name": "Vegetable Stir-Fry with Tofu",
      "ingredients": [
        "tofu",
        "broccoli",
        "carrots",
        "bell peppers",
        "snap peas",
        "soy sauce",
        "sesame oil",
        "garlic",
        "ginger",
        "rice",
        "green onions"
      ],
      "total_calories": 350,
      "nutrition": {
        "carbs": "40g",
        "protein": "15g",
        "fat": "12g"
      },
      "budget": "12 USD"
    },
    {
      "recipe_name": "Quinoa Stuffed Bell Peppers",
      "ingredients": [
        "bell peppers",
        "quinoa",
        "black beans",
        "corn",
        "tomato",
        "onion",
        "garlic",
        "cumin",
        "paprika",
        "salt",
        "pepper"
      ],
      "total_calories": 300,
      "nutrition": {
        "carbs": "35g",
        "protein": "10g",
        "fat": "11g"
      },
      "budget": "10 USD"
    },
    {
      "recipe_name": "Cauliflower Rice Bowl with Black Beans and Avocado",
      "ingredients": [
        "cauliflower",
        "black beans",
        "avocado",
        "corn",
        "red cabbage",
        "lime",
        "cilantro",
        "cumin",
        "paprika",
        "salt",
        "pepper"
      ],
      "total_calories": 280,
      "nutrition": {
        "carbs": "30g",
        "protein": "9g",
        "fat": "10g"
      },
      "budget": "10 USD"
    },
    {
      "recipe_name": "Mushroom and Spinach Quinoa Risotto",
      "ingredients": [
        "quinoa",
        "mushrooms",
        "spinach",
        "onion",
        "garlic",
        "vegetable broth",
        "white wine",
        "parmesan cheese",
        "olive oil",
        "salt",
        "pepper"
      ],
      "total_calories": 310,
      "nutrition": {
        "carbs": "35g",
        "protein": "11g",
        "fat": "12g"
      },
      "budget": "12 USD"
    },
    {
      "recipe_name": "Spicy Lentil and Chickpea Stew",
      "ingredients": [
        "lentils",
        "chickpeas",
        "onion",
        "carrots",
        "celery",
        "garlic",
        "tomato",
        "vegetable broth",
        "cumin",
        "coriander",
        "smoked paprika",
        "cayenne pepper",
        "salt",
        "pepper",
        "lemon"
      ],
      "total_calories": 340,
      "nutrition": {
        "carbs": "40g",
        "protein": "14g",
        "fat": "13g"
      },
      "budget": "10 USD"
    }
  ]
}
```